# Sharepoint document library: save a generated pdf

Tags: sharepoint, office365, jspdf, sharepoint-apps

Is there a way to save directly a pdf generated with the jspdf library, to a document library in sharepoint online?

I need a solution in javascript, C# is not an option in my case. It's a sharepoint hosted add-in that I'm developing.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, but you may get a better response on sharepoint.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way combining jsPDF and Rest services for Sharepoint.

Comment: Can you please share this solution ? Thanks